# Data in a XML node into a table

Tags: .net, sql-server, xpath, xml-parsing

edited:

```
 <people>
        <person>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <age>21</age>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Jane Smith</name>
            <age>24</age>
        </person>
    </people>
```

actualy what i want to know is how to get both name and age at the same time using xpath.
i can retrieve name by using

```
string fileName = "testinfo.xml";
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(fileName);

            XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathExpression expr;
            expr = nav.Compile("/People/Person/name");
            XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

           try{
               while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {

                XPathNavigator nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();
                Console.WriteLine("name" + nav2.Value);

            }
            }
catch(Exception ex) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

i need to get name and age in the while loop by iterating through the xml node just once.
sorry for not been clear.

Comment: You __must__ use xpath? Linq to XML is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found what i was looking for guys.

```
 expr = nav.Compile("/people/person/*[self::name or self::age]");
```

with the above i can get both name and age nodes at the same time using xpath.how ever i found all your answers very interesting.

thanx

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a couple comments on your question:

Your XML example doesn't really lend itself to easy answering. Let's change it to something more semantics-friendly (is that a word?):

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>21</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jane Smith</name>
        <age>24</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

Your question doesn't really mention what **you** tried to solve the problem. As NovaJoe said, coding this would be quite trivial using Linq-to-XML and Linq-to-SQL, so how do **you** prefer interacting with your database? Have you written C# code in the past to connect to a database? Are you familiar with LINQ? (*If not, you should learn it!*)

To convince you how badly you should go learn the above technologies, if you're not already familiar with them, I whipped up a quick example of Linq-to-XML and Linq-to-SQL, using the excellent program [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/):

I had the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Age] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_People] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I used LinqPAD to just open up a standard Linq-to-SQL connection for me:
[image: sample linqpad database connection]

Finally, the C# code:

```
// Connect to the database using linq-to-sql
var db = new TypedDataContext();

// Load the xml file using linq-to-xml
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\path\to\file\people.xml");
var people = doc.Descendants("person");
foreach (var person in people)
{
    // Create person object
    var personObject = new People();
    personObject.Name = person.Descendants("name").Single().Value;
    personObject.Age = Convert.ToInt32(person.Descendants("age").Single().Value);
    // Queue to add person to database
    db.People.InsertOnSubmit(personObject);
}

// Finally, submit any pending changes
db.SubmitChanges();
```

This resulted in the following data going into my database:

[image: table with data]

Answer (score 3):

You're not telling us much how you want to do this - stored procedure? Ad-hoc SQL query from your app? What does your table look like??

Based on your input, you can parse this into a "pseudo-table" or rows and columns with this SQL XQuery expression:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<element1>
    <element2>
        <element3>b</element3>
        <element4>c</element4>
    </element2>
    <element2>
        <element3>b</element3>
        <element4>c</element4>
    </element2>
</element1>'

SELECT
    e2.value('(element3)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Element3',
    e2.value('(element4)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Element4'
FROM
    @input.nodes('/element1/element2') AS E1(E2)
```

This returns an output of:

```
Element3    Element4
   b           c
   b           c
```

and of course, you could also write an `INSERT INTO .......` statement instead of just a `SELECT` based on that output of rows/columns and insert your parsed XML data into a relational table. You could e.g. have a stored procedure that takes a parameter of type `XML` from your C# app, and then do the parsing and inserting into the table inside that stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your database implementation. If I had to do it, I'd use Linq-to-XML to extract the values from the XML nodes, and then I'd use LINQ-to-SQL for shoving it in the database.